# swift ui アラート Cannot use instance member '$text' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift

swift ui で

TextEditorをインスタンス化しようとすると

Cannot use instance member '$text' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

というアラートが出ます。

let textEditor = TextEditor(text: $text)

としています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いくつか問題があるので、上げていきます。

1. Stored Propertyでは宣言時に他のPropertyは使えない
2. SwiftUIにてViewは基本的に変数にしない

おそらくこのようなコードになっていると思います。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text: String = "Hello"
  
  let textEditor = TextEditor(text: $text) // Cannot use instance member '$text' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
  
  var body: some View {
    textEditor
  }
}
```

### 問題1: 解決方法

Computed Propertyにする

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text: String = "Hello"
  
  var textEditor: TextEditor { TextEditor(text: $text) }
  
  var body: some View {
    textEditor
  }
}
```

### 問題2: Viewを変数にしない

これは流派とか考え方の一例なので絶対ではありません。

Viewを切り出したい時、変数化、struct化を選ぶときの基準は、Previewするほどかという点です。
Previewが必要ないのであればstructを選びましょう。

以下が参考になります。

https://speakerdeck.com/uhooi/iosdc-japan-2022

### 自分だったら

もしTextEditorを比較的複雑なカスタマイズをするのであれば別structに切り出します。

そうでなければbody内で直接使います。

#### 例1

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text: String = "Hello"
  
  var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $text)
  }
}
```

#### 例2

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text: String = "Hello"
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      RichTextEditor(text: $text)
    }
  }
}

struct RichTextEditor: View {
  @Binding var text: String
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Editor")
        .padding()
        .border(.blue)
        .padding()
      
      TextEditor(text: $text)
    }
    .border(.red, width: 5)
  }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。